# Login to a site using cURL

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I'm currently trying to write a script that will connect to a site using cURL.

I lookod for the ways to do that, and tried cookies, but I didn't know what cookie is the login cookie... if anyone can help thanks...

But I tried another way... Using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS but than I found out that the site is using GET on the login form (WHAT?!) So I tried this:

```
$username="User"; 
$password="Pass"; 
$url="http://www.site.com/register/?action=login&user=".$username."&password=".$password;
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

But it didn't work... Is there any way to login to a site differently? The site has "method=GET" but it's not really using get...

```
<form method="get" action="/register/" name="connectform">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login"/><input type="hidden" name="returnpage" value=""/>
            <ul class="login_form">
                <li><label>login :</label> <input type="text" name="login_login" maxlength="24" value="" class="input2"/><span class="error"></span></li>
                <li><label>Password :</label> <input type="password"  name="login_password" maxlength="24" value="" class="input2"/><span class="error"></span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="login_button" style="display:inline-block">
                <a class="small_button" onclick="javascript:document.connectform.submit()"><span>Connect to my account</span></a>
                <input type="submit" style="display:none" />
            </div>  
            </div>
            </form>
```

What should I do?
I don't care wich of these ways you'll help me but I prefer the cookies way...
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with following url:

```
$url = 'http://www.site.com/register/?action=login&login_login='.$username.'&login_password='.$password;
```

Also add these options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    // return the content (often default)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);    // follow redirects
```

And if you want to get to other pages that require the login above, use following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');    // send saved cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');     // save cookies
```

Solution: Look at the comments below.

Comment: Yes I did that before, I just edited the names when I wrote it here.

Comment: Could you tell us in which page you want to login? I'd like to watch the network activities so that I can help you. Or just do it self with the developer tools that are included in the most popular browsers (like Google Chrome; press F12 and then go to Network and login to the page).

Comment: Thanks DragonWork! I looked in the Network section and I found the solution! I forgot one of the get fields.

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer above as solution, I will add my comment to the post.

Comment: Now I have another problem, I need after the login to go to another page at the site, so I just did this before closing the cURL connection:curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
But the login is lost... I did the cookie thing you told me to...

Comment: Don't close the cURL connection. This will free all resources and destroy the ch handler. Simply change CURLOPT_URL and execute again.